# Open only one dialog from ribbon

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have a ribbon with Login button, which opens the login dialog. I want to limit number of dialogs to one.
I'm using function:
[`displayDialogAsync(startAddress, options, callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-)

All I found is:

> An Office Add-in task pane can have only one dialog box open at any time. Multiple dialogs can be open at the same time from Add-in Commands (custom ribbon buttons or menu items).

But I want to use ribbon button. So is there a way to do it? (maybe global variable or smth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need a global indicator, but each dialog is a completely separate instance of the JavaScript runtime, so a global variable won't work. You need to use LocalStorage. Try creating a LocalStorage key with a name like isDialogOpen. Your code checks its value before it opens the dialog. If it is false, your code opens the dialog and sets it to true.

Comment: Yea, I tried global variable with no success. Gonna use LocalStorage. Thanks!

Comment: If I am using this solution, and Excel crashes while the Dialog is open next time I'll open Excel I won't be able to open it since the local storage value of isDialogOpen is true. How one can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Actually closing Excel while the dialog is open is enough, you can't open the dialog unless you clean the cache

Comment: Can you fix this by resetting isDialogOpen to false when the add-in starts up? (e.g., do this at the end of the Office.initialize or Office.onReady method.